# probability mass function fitting

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

I have a probability mass function of some experimental data who's log looks like the following: (please ignore the fact that it is not normalized)
![alt text][1]

[image shack image removed]

(meaning if p(x) is the pmf, this is log(p(x)) )
Does anyone know what parametric family it might belong to? (note that this is a discrete distribution)

Comment: The graph kind of looks like a rotated Fermi-Dirac distribution... Can you give some information about where this data is coming from? Do you have any theoretical model to compare it to?

Comment: Sigmoids ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function ) are all over the place in probability laws. You should try to fit the examples linked to in Wikipedia.

Comment: if anything it is more of an inverse sigmoid.
It came from the distribution of certain image features after they have been quantized (it is the distribution of a sort of 'visual vocabulary'). The distribution is from a large database of images with no special characteristic (natural + synthetic images).

Comment: So the y axis is log-number of features falling in a particular bin, and X is just feature index sorted by popularity?

Comment: sheldon: exactly

Comment: Alas, without the image, it's pretty much impossible to tell what this old question is asking. The only answer below suffers from [the same problem](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2386/imageshack-images-turning-into-ad-banners) too.

Comment: Since without the image the question is meaningless, and since the OP has visited the site for the last time 4 years ago, I am voting to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 2):

I tried taking the logarithm to the pdf of a $\beta(0.5, 1.5)$ (see [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)) and it gave me this

[image shack image removed]

Maybe this can be fitted for your data.

Comment: The Beta-family seems a really good guess, though at this point it is just what it is: an educated guess. If liza could explain to us what and how has been measured, we might say more :).

Comment: Very interesting! I'll try it